# Range slider thumb is not showing on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a range slider on my web which is working fine on all browser other than IE. I am using background image for thumb but that image is not showing on IE and also i am using pseudo element to show starting and ending point, which is also not visible on IE. Here is my code

```
 <input type="range" data-link="test" class="range-slider__range" min="500" step="500" max="10000">

input.range-slider__range {
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 max-width:100%;
 height: 2px;
 border:1px solid #06C3C3 !important;
 outline: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 50px 0;}

input.range-slider__range:before {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -3px;
  left: -2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #06C3C3;}

input.range-slider__range:after {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  top: -3px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #06C3C3;}

.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/40/000/fff.jpg");
  width: 186px;
  height: 49px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: url("https://dummyimage.com/40/000/fff.jpg");
  width: 186px;
  height: 49px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `:-webkit-slider-thumb` and `::-moz-range-thumb` which, by their name, are properties for `webkit` browsers like chrome/safari etc. and `moz` which is for `mozilla firefox` .

So of course it won't appear on IE. For IE you can use `::-ms-thumb` together with `ms-track`

`:after,:before` are `pseudo-elements` that are used to insert content after of the before the content of an element. `input` elements do not have content. ( just like `img` or `hr` etc. ). So the behavior in IE,  to NOT display `:after` or `:before` on a 'non-content' HTML element.
, is the correct one.

You can wrap your input inside a `label` and add `pseudo-elements` to it.

Example below ( for IE )

```css
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
  width: 300px;
  height: 5px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
  border: none;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: goldenrod;
}

label {
  position: Relative;
}

label:after,
label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 7px;
  height: 7px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #06C3C3;
}

label:before {
  left: 2px;
}

label:after {
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="range" data-link="test" class="range-slider__range" min="500" step="500" max="10000">
</label>
```